# Is it possible to connect MetaMask or other wallet, to a Xamarin app?

Tags: xamarin, metamask, nft

I want to sell NFT's from mobile game, based on Xamarin. I was wondering that connecting to MetaMask would be the first step. But how to do that?

Comment: Do they have Android/iOS libraries?  If so, then you can generate Xamarin bindings for them.

Comment: That is a way, but not the easiest one. I would like to see some nuget package.

Comment: I found this nuget but I don't know how it works, yet
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WalletConnect.Core/

Answer (score 0):

You can search nuget package in you nuget package manager, rightclick your solution, and choose manage your nuget package, and search for the walletconnect
and install it to enable it in your project.

Comment: But that's just a general guide how to look for nuget package.. Have you found any useful packages targeting Xamarin ?

Comment: you can try search for some example like this one https://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/nethereum-ui-wallets/